# What should I do to have the user set their own order number with in my code?

Tags: java, class

I am a beginner programmer and I don't understand why I can not set the orderNum in my driver. I want the user to be able to set the orderNum on their own because there is no orderNum the is predisposed.

```
public class Cafe 
{
    private int orderNum;
    private String cafeName, cafeID;

    public Cafe()
    {
        int orderNum;
        String cafeName = null, cafeID;
    }
    public String setName(String cafeID)
    {
        if(cafeID.equals("101"))
            cafeName = "Essex Cafe";
        else if(cafeID.equals("252"))
            cafeName = "White Marsh Cafe";
        else
            cafeName = "Towson Cafe";
        return cafeName;
    }
    public String toString()
    {

        return "\t" + cafeName + "\nOrder Number = " + orderNum;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CafeProject 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cafe Emp = new Cafe();

    System.out.print("Enter Cafe Identifier:    ");
    Emp.setName(scan.next());




    System.out.print(Emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to set String cafeName to null or redeclare orderNum in your constructor. When you call the Cafe constructor, it will automatically initialize the instance variables to defaults unless otherwise specified (0 for int, null for string). I would also get rid of the return statement in setName() and change the method from String to void. You can include a separate getName() method that returns cafeName if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Change your program like this you can set order no manually

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Cafe
{
    private int orderNum;
    private String cafeName, cafeID;

    public Cafe()
    {        int orderNum;
        String cafeName = null, cafeID;
    }
    public String setName(String cafeID)
    {
        if(cafeID.equals("101"))
            cafeName = "Essex Cafe";
        else if(cafeID.equals("252"))
            cafeName = "White Marsh Cafe";
        else
            cafeName = "Towson Cafe";
        return cafeName;
    }
    public void setOrderNo(int orderNo){
        orderNum=orderNo;
    }
    public String toString()
    {

        return "\t" + cafeName + "\nOrder Number = " + orderNum;
    }
}

public class CafeProject
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Cafe Emp = new Cafe();

    System.out.print("Enter Cafe Identifier:    ");
    Emp.setName(scan.next());
    System.out.print("Enter Order No:    ");
    Emp.setOrderNo(scan.nextInt());



    System.out.print(Emp);
    }
}
```

You just need a function to set order